# MYSQL: Speed up import of prices

Tags: mysql, import

I need to speed up an import in MySQL.
Let's assume that i have an external table "external.prices"

| articleNumber | price | regionNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "A0000000001" | 1.90 | "R1" |
| "A0000000001" | 1.99 | "R2" |
| "A0000000002" | 4.99 | "R1" |

Internally i have the following tables

"internal.articles"

| id | articleNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "A0000000001" |
| 2 | "A0000000002" |

"internal.regions"

| id | regionNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "R1" |
| 2 | "R2" |

"internal.prices" (empty)

| articleID | regionID | price |
| --- | --- | --- |

Now i need to fill the "internal.prices" table from "external.prices".

In my thoughts the fastest way to import was:

1. Also adding column "articleNumber" and "regionNumber" to internal.prices.
   like this:

| articleID | regionID | price | articleNumber | regionNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

2. Then directly inserting the prices with this insert:

```
    INSERT INTO internal.prices
    (articleNumber, regionNumber, price)
    (SELECT articleNumber, regionNumber, price FROM external.prices)
```

3. Then updating the articleID and regionID whith this update:

```
    UPDATE internal.prices p
    SET p.articleID = (SELECT id 
                        FROM internal.articles 
                        WHERE articleNumber = p.articleNumber ),
        p.regionID = (SELECT id 
                        FROM internal.regions 
                        WHERE regionNumber = p.regionNumber )
```

Turns out the first insert is extremly fast, but updating the articleID and regionID is very very slow especially for a large number of prices.
Note: I already have indexes on articleNumber and regionNumber in all tables.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One query can do this everything (except adding columns, of course):

```sql
INSERT INTO internal.prices (articleID, articleNumber, regionID, regionNumber, price)
SELECT a.id, articleNumber, r.id, regionNumber, p.price 
FROM external.prices p
JOIN internal.articles a USING (articleNumber)
JOIN internal.regions r USING (regionNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing the entire table, then there is a better way:  Load the new table, RENAME TABLE, then DROP TABLE.

If the incoming data is partial, then use IODKU rather than UPDATE.  This automatically inserts or updates in a single step.

(Your "3" looks unworkable.")